# Compatibility of Mathematica 10 and Endnote 7 on OS X

Tags: interoperability, mac-os-x, citation-management

Given the new updates, are [*EndNote 7*](http://endnote.com/) and *Mathematica 10* compatible when running on OS X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I have not heard from anyone I have gotten a copy myself and tested it. It does not work with mathematica and endnote 7 on osx.